# Linear regression - minimum sample size

Tags: regression, sample-size

I would like to perform a simple linear regression on data that shows a clear linear relationship.

How to determine the minimum sample size for a simple linear regression analysis?

My sample size is small, so even if the linear relationship is evident, I don't know how to determine if the sample size is adequate or not.

Thank you very much!

Comment: any reason you aren't looking at the standard errors for your parameter estimates?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suppose the *minimum* is 2.  But it really depends on what the goal is.  If all you want to do is hint at a linear relationship, you won't need many.  If your goal is to perform a test of hypothesis that the coefficient for the slope of your line has a particular sign, you can do a sample size calculation to obtain a pre-specified statistical power.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to do. For instance, if you want a specific statistical power there are tables that show what sample size you need to achieve this given various assumptions such as the population effect size. There are also rules of thumb created by various authors based on their own experience on how much data you need - but this is essentially their own opinion not based on any mathematical reality. Some realities in your data require a larger sample size. Violations of assumptions sometimes become less serve if you have larger sample sizes (for example normality).

Answer (score 0):

David G. Jenkins and Pedro F. Quintana-Ascencio (2020) suggested:

> We conclude that a minimum $N = 8$ is informative given very little variance, but minimum $N ≥ 25$ is required for more variance.

> Insufficient $N$ and $R^2$-based model selection apparently contribute to confusion and low reproducibility in various disciplines. To avoid those problems, we recommend that research based on regressions or meta-regressions use $N ≥ 25$.

https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0229345